# how to get the values from a nested queryset of list in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, list, django-views

table structure:

```
 -------------------------------------
|    id     |      keywords           |
 =====================================
|    1      |   animals,orange ball   |
|-----------|-------------------------|
|    2      |animals,pet, dog,as usual|
|-----------|-------------------------|
|    3      |'anime, animations,superhero,cartoon'|
|_____________________________________|
```

`views.py`

```
    TagList = ImgDetails.objects.values_list('keywords').order_by('keywords')
```

I'm getting value from database in a queryset:

**output:**

```
<QuerySet [('animals,orange ball',), ('animals,pet, dog,as usual',), ('animals',), ('animals',), ('animals, pet,dog',), ('animals, pet,dog',), ('animals, pet,dog',), ('animals,fore
st,tiger,lion',), ('animals,forest,tiger,lion',), ('animation,sasuke,cartoon,anime',), ('anime, animations,superhero,cartoon',), ('anime, animations,superhero,cartoo
n',), ('anime, animations,superhero,cartoon',), ('anime, animations,superhero,cartoon',), ('cat,deer',), ('cat,deer',), ('nature, forest, greenry',), ('nature, fores
t, greenry',), ('nature, forest, greenry',)]>
```

I want to fetch all the unique values or your can say string from the queryset in a list like this:

```
['animals','orange ball','anime','animations','superhero','cartoon','dog','tiger','forest','animation']
```

I can use nested for loop to get it done. But is there any simple way to get string from queryset in a list.

Answer (score 0):

You should get list of tuples by following query:

```
image_details = ImgDetails.objects.annotate(keyword_list=Func(F('keywords'),Value(','),function='string_to_array'))
```

now you can get list of `keywords` in `keyword_list` field.

Comment: i don't think i can use ```distinct()``` on ```imgdetails``` object as if you see. keywords column uses ```animals,orange ball``` as a one string of one field and ```animals,pet, dog,as usual``` as another string of 2nd field. which will always be distinct.

Comment: best practice for this case is using `array_field` or normalize database.
but you can use `string_to_array` function in postgres(if you are using postgres).
`image_details = ImgDetails.objects.annotate(keyword_list=Func(F('keywords'),Value(','),function='string_to_array'))`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether its right way of doing it or not but i'm using it:

```
def getTags():

    TagList = ImgDetails.objects.values_list('keywords', flat=True).order_by('keywords')

    tagsuggestions = set([item for sublist in TagList for item in str(sublist).split(',')])

    return tagsuggestions
```